# Tensorflow hub vs tf.keras.applications for transfer learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, efficientnet

I'm trying to figure out what is the difference between using a pretrained model from tensorflow hub versus using the very same architecture from tf.keras.applications. I've tried training 2 models with the same architecture - one from tf hub, an the other one from tf.keras.applications, which should yeild comparable results, however the results are vastly different. Could you please explain the difference?

Here are examples of the two models.

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(include_top = False)
base_model.trainable = False
 
inputs = Input(shape = (224,224,3), name = 'input_layer')
x = base_model(inputs, training = False)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name = 'global_avg_pool_layer')(x)
outputs = Dense(len(class_names), activation = 'softmax', name = 'output_layer')(x)
 
model_1 = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
 
model_1.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = Adam(), metrics = ['accuracy'])
 
history_1 = model_1.fit(train_data_all_10_percent,
                        epochs = 10,
                        validation_data = test_data,
                        validation_steps = (0.15 * len(test_data)))
```

AND THE SECOND

```
efficientnet_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientnet/b0/feature-vector/1'
 
def create_model(model_url, num_classes = 10):
  feature_extractor_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model_url, trainable = False, name = 'feature_extraction_layer', input_shape = IMG_SIZE + (3,))
  model = Sequential([
                      feature_extractor_layer,
                      Dense(len(class_names), activation = 'softmax', name = 'output_layer')
  ])
  return model
 
efficientnet_model = create_model(efficientnet_model , num_classes = len(class_names))
efficientnet_model .compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',  optimizer = Adam(), metrics = ['accuracy'])
efficientnet_history = efficientnet_model .fit(train_data_all_10_percent, 
                 epochs = 10,
                 validation_data = test_data, 
                 validation_steps = 0.15 * len(test_data))
```

Comment: Can you check this similar SO Query?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60284154/11530462